# rpcsvchost using 99% CPU on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook

Recently I noticed that my fan got really loud even when just doing simple tasks as searching with my browser on Google. The Activity manager of my MacBook Pro (Late 2011, running OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5) showed that during these times a process named `rpcsvchost` is using about 99 % CPU.

Apart from similar complaints by other people on the web I couldn't find any information about this process. What is it doing and why is it using so much CPU?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6522468?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @Tommy Have you found any solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

rpcsvchost Is some sort of Remote Process host, it helps thing connect your computer securely remotely to a thing. Some banks require a "trustee" application of some sort. It could also be related to a remote access software. In my case, Team Viewer was causing it to run away. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

@Caleb has already briefly described what the process does. Strange as it may sound, for me what worked was emptying up the trash bin. Just try and see if it works.

Credit for this approach and more information:

[What is ‘rpcsvchost’ and Why is it running on my Mac?](https://appuals.com/what-is-rpcsvchost-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-mac/)